# Posting savescreen to FB

Tags: android, ios, facebook, coronasdk

I need help to solve this problem: I want to post on FB a save screen from my app (I got save screen by using display.save function). Everything works fine on Android while on my iPad it crashes! Please find the function code below:

```
local function postonFB( event)
    display.save( tab3fields, { filename="ticket.jpg", baseDir=system.DocumentsDirectory, isFullResolution=true, backgroundColor={0, 0, 0, 0} } )

    local fbAppID = "4531113981XXXXX"  
    local function fbListener( event )
        if event.phase == "login" then
            local attachment = {
                message="I am a champion!",
                source= {baseDir=system.DocumentsDirectory, filename="ticket.jpg", type="image"}
            }

            facebook.request("me/photos", "POST", attachment)
            native.showAlert("Facebook", "Submitted!")
        end
    end

    -- photo uploading requires the "publish_actions" permission
    facebook.login( fbAppID, fbListener, { "publish_actions" } )
end
```

Please help, I am getting crazy to understand what's wrong!
Thanks a lot. Ubaldo

Comment: If it crashes, look for an error message in console, and post it here. Also, have a look at Rob's article regarding code formatting here: https://coronalabs.com/blog/2015/06/09/tutorial-the-value-of-well-formatted-code/

Comment: Thank you Mequiades. I'll try to get the message and I will be back soon.

Comment: As i said I have no error messages. Terminal sais that Facebook Connect and Facebook.login cannot be tried on Simulator and so I need to test them on devices. So when I test on Android it works while when I test on iOS it crashes!

Answer (score 0):

here is my facebook sharing code:

```
baseDir = system.DocumentsDirectory
display.save( group , "screenshot.png", system.DocumentsDirectory )

local facebook = require "facebook"
local fbAppID = "898209XXXXXXXXX" 

function onLoginSuccess()
    attachment = {
    message = "i got ".. score .. " blablabla",
    source = { baseDir=system.DocumentsDirectory, filename="screenshot.png", type="image" }
    }
    facebook.request( "me/photos", "POST", attachment )
end

function fbListener( event )
    if event.isError then
        native.showAlert( "ERROR", event.response, { "OK" } )
    else
        if event.type == "session" and event.phase == "login" then
            onLoginSuccess()
        elseif event.type == "request" then
            print("upload done")
        end
    end
end
facebook.login( fbAppID, fbListener, { "publish_stream", "publish_actions" } )
```

ps do you have this in you build.settings?

```
plugins =
{
    ["facebook"] =
    {
        publisherId = "com.coronalabs"
    },

},
```

Comment: Yes, I did. In CFBundleURLSchemes I put "fbXXXXXXXXXX" where XXXXX is the Facebook appID.

Comment: strange ps have a look at the native.* — Social Plugin  https://github.com/coronalabs/plugins-sample-native-popup-social

Comment: Thanks a lot mmkevind. I pasted your code but it did not work. I connected my iPAD to Xcode and i got this log errors: 
Jun 17 08:28:15 iPad-di-Ubaldo lineitup[1795] <Error>: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'com.facebook.sdk:InvalidOperationException', reason: 'FBSession: No AppID provided; either pass an AppID to init, or add a string valued key with the appropriate id named FacebookAppID to the bundle *.plist' I think I pass all the info requested but for some reasons FB does not get them...:(

Comment: ps make sure you have the "iPhone Store ID" & "iPad Store ID" filed in plus "Single Sign On = yes" & "Deep Linking = yes" on developers.facebook.com/apps/ see photo : i.imgur.com/vaGQvoG.png ... sometimes you can only do this when the app is in the app store

Comment: I have SSO=yes and deep linkking=yes. I do not have any iPhoe or iPAD ID since my app is still in development. What shall I do in the meanwhile?

Comment: im working on a new game and will add the fb share to it lets see if im getting the same error.... be a couple of days

Comment: Great! I will wait for you then! As far AS I know everything seems OK, on Android works! There might be a problem in passing FB App ID to Facebook...

Comment: my feeling is that it will work when you have the app id's

Comment: As I said I have the FB App ID (it works on Android) but I don't have the iOS App Store ID. Are you talking about that?

Comment: Hi there! Any news?Thanks for your support mmkevind.

Comment: I am using corona SDK 2653. Did you configure FB App with iOS Store ID's?If yes what about if you remove it?

Comment: I don't know how Corona Facebook integration works, but I would check the XCode project for these thigs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started#appid. Pay special attention to Create a Facebook App and Configure an Xcode Project. Make sure your XCode project has the necessary configurations for the Facebook SDK to work.

Comment: i have a look in when i remove the ID's